# Converting html to textual representation with preserved whitespace meaning of tags -- how?

Tags: javascript, html, text, representation

Consider such html piece:

```
<p>foo</p><p>bar</p>
```

If you run (for example) jQuery `text` for it you will get "foobar" -- so it is raw text actually, not textual representation.

I am looking for some ready to use library to get textual representation, in this case it should be -- "foo\nbar". Or clever hints how to make this as easy as possible ;-).

**NOTE**: I am not looking for beautiful output text, but just preserved meaning of whitespaces, so for:

```
<tr><td>foo</td><td>bar</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
```

I will be happy with

```
foo bar
1 2
```

it does NOT have to be:

```
foo bar
1   2
```

(but of course no harm done).

Comment: This is highly dependent on your css as well

Comment: a simple solution would be to replace the closing tr and p tag with \n and the closing td tag with a space and then strip all html tags from the input.. but it depends on your css as well..

Comment: I would agree with lejzz though maybe suggest a tab instead of a space for close td tags, just to try to minimise confusion with spaces inside the cells.

Comment: you could also use the \t for tab inbetween your foo and bar then 1 and 2

Comment: Thank you all, it does not have to beautiful, it can do a minimal work -- even the space is better than joining all text together as `text` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the [`innerText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533899%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.textContent) properties?

```
function getText(element){
    var s = "";
    if(element.innerText){
        s = element.innerText;
    }else if(element.textContent){
        s = element.textContent;
    }
    return s;
}
```

*Example*

Adds a PRE tag to the body and appends the body text.

```
document.body.appendChild(
    document.createElement('pre')
)
.appendChild(
    document.createTextNode(
        getText(document.body)
    )
);
```

---

**Edit**

Does using a range work with firefox?

```
var r = document.createRange();
r.selectNode(document.body);
console.log(r.toString());
```

---

**Edit**

It looks like you're stuck with a parsing function like this then.

```
var parse = function(element){
    var s = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++){
        if(/^(iframe|noscript|script|style)$/i.test(element.childNodes[i].nodeName)){
            continue;
        }else if(/^(tr|br|p|hr)$/i.test(element.childNodes[i].nodeName)){
            s+='\n';
        }else if(/^(td|th)$/.test(element.childNodes[i].nodeName)){
            s+='\t';
        }

        if(element.childNodes[i].nodeType == 3){
            s+=element.childNodes[i].nodeValue.replace(/[\r\n]+/, "");
        }else{
            s+=parse(element.childNodes[i]);
        }
    }
    return s;
}

console.log(parse(document.body));
```

Comment: It does with my tests on chrome. Are you sure it isn't that whitespace is being collapsed by the web browser in your tests?

Comment: So you really get `foo bar` here (http://jsfiddle.net/Hf3vJ/)? I don't. And how should a browser determine where to insert whitespaces anyway?

Comment: Yes, see screenshot. What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome. You are just showing the HTML output (which of course shows `foo` and `bar` in separate lines as each of them is in `p` element), not the console output. But anyways, I noticed that `innerText` apparently inserts whitespaces, but `textContent` does not. See http://jsfiddle.net/Hf3vJ/1/. Given that `textContent` is the W3C standard and `innerText` is not supported in Firefox, I would not rely on that behaviour.

Comment: I tested also FF (undefined+foobar) and Opera (foobar+foobar) so in major browsers this solution does not insert any whitespace (so in short, it is not solution for the problem) -- it outputs raw text.

Comment: @zapthedingbat,  seems like we started coding the tree traverse at the same time, I will post my version in a second.

Answer (score 0):

I started writing my own function probably at the same time as Zapthedingbat, so just for the record:

```
var NodeTypeEnum = { Element    : 1,Attribute   : 2, Text:  3, Comment  :8,Document     :9};

function doTextualRepresentation(elem)
{
    if (elem.nodeType==NodeTypeEnum.Text)
        return elem.nodeValue;
    else if (elem.nodeType==NodeTypeEnum.Element || elem.nodeType==NodeTypeEnum.Document)
    {
        var s = "";

        var child = elem.firstChild;
        while (child!=null)
        {
            s += doTextualRepresentation(child);
            child = child.nextSibling;
        }

        if (['P','DIV','TABLE','TR','BR','HR'].indexOf(elem.tagName)>-1)
            s = "\n"+s+"\n";
        else if (['TD','TR'].indexOf(elem.tagName)>-1)
            s = "\t"+s+"\t";

        return s;

    }

    return "";
}

function TextualRepresentation(elem)
{
    return doTextualRepresentation(elem).replace(/\n[\s]+/g,"\n").replace(/\t{2,}/g,"\t");
}
```

One thing I am surprised with -- I couldn't get

```
for (var child in elem.childNodes)
```

working, and it is a pity, because I spend most time in C# and I like this syntax, theoretically it should work in JS, but it doesn't.

Comment: because childNodes is an array javascript yields the index of each item in the array rather than the value. you can use the syntax however you must use it like this: for(var childIndex in elem.childNodes){var child = elem.childNodes[childIndex];}